# problem Laravel 500 Server in deploying app in the forge

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with Laravel and the 500 server error,
on my local host it works but I published the app and all routes work except the main one which is /dashboard, before it worked but I added an option to send emails (all the data is already in the env) and this happened, before it worked but Not anymore, I already changed the route, the view, etc. but I can't get it to work.

I updated composer, cleared view cache, routes etc and it still doesn't work

"Application\models\Instalacion"
The problem indicates that it is the model, but the model does exist since it works on localhost

```
[2023-10-03 15:47:25] production.ERROR: Class "App\models\Instalacion" not found {"userId":2,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class \"App\\models\\Instalacion\" not found at /home/forge/default/app/Http/Controllers/EmpresaController.php:217)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\EmpresaController->instalaciones()
#1 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction()
#2 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(259): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#3 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(205): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#4 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(799): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#5 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#6 /home/forge/default/app/Http/Middleware/CheckRole.php(28): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#7 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): App\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckRole->handle()
#8 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#9 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#10 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#11 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle()
#12 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#13 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#14 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#15 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle()
#16 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(121): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#17 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handleStatefulRequest()
#18 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle()
#19 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#20 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#21 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#22 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle()
#23 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#24 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(798): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#25 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(777): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#26 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(741): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#27 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(730): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#28 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(200): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#29 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#30 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#31 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#32 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#33 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#34 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#35 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#36 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#37 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#38 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(99): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#39 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#40 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/HandleCors.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#41 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors->handle()
#42 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#43 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle()
#44 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#45 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(175): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#46 /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(144): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#47 /home/forge/default/public/index.php(51): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#48 {main}
"}
```

Comment: An `HTTP 500 Server Error` is a catch-all for any number of issues that can happen... You'll need to check your server logs, or your Laravel logs (`storage\logs\laravel.log`) and find the specific error message, file and line of code that is triggering this error, end [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77223581/edit) to include that information, otherwise, none of us can help you.

Comment: sorry, here it is

Comment: Perfect. So, your local dev environment is "case insensitive", so `App\models\Instalacion` works. But most production environments are "case sensitive", so it should be `App\Models\Instalacion` (Capital `M` vs `m` on `Models`). If you fix that and redeploy, you should be good.

Comment: All good! It's a frustrating one that I've run into on a few occasions too... It's annoying when things work flawlessly locally, then explode on production, but thankfully, this is an easily fixable one. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful to use the correct capitalisation. Laravels namespaces are by default in PascalCase:

```php
use App\Models\Instalacion;
```

In your code, the `models` part of the namespace is lowercase:

```php
use App\models\Instalacion;
```